# Best Practice to get related values in django without DoesNotExist error

Tags: django, django-models

If I have two models in Django:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    author = models.CharField()

class Post(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog)
```

And I want to get all posts for a given blog:

```
Blog.objects.get(author='John').post_set
```

If there is a Blog with `author='John'` but not posts, a `DoesNotExist` exception is raised.  What is the best solution to this?

I can do a `try..except` on the front-end, or a custom manager method.  Is there a way to generally override Django to return an empty set?  For my purposes, `DoesNotExist` isn't useful.

Alternately, the whole issue can be sidestepped with:

```
Blog.objects.select_related('post').get(author='John').post_set.values()
```

Comment: I don't think `get_object_or_None` will quite work for you in this situation, but you might find http://bitbucket.org/offline/django-annoying/wiki/Home useful for similar issues.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can also avoid the error by using `Post.objects.filter(blog__author='John')`

Comment: +1 this would be the standard practice, most easily recognized by another developer, and is semantically equivalent to the OP's goal.

Comment: Something that wasn't clear from the original post is that this is all happening inside of a model method inside of Blog.  Yours is probably the most parsimonious solution but I already have the Blog object instantiated, it would be great to use it.

Comment: The method suggested by Ben uses a class method on the Post class which is already instantiated. The fact that you already have a Blog instance is irrelevant since filterspecs are created from class models not the object instances.

Comment: Adam, in my experience when dealing with non-trivially complex queries the path of least resistance in Django will be to start with the Manager of the Model for which you want to get instances (in this case `Post.objects`).