# Django foreignkey query

Tags: django

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    a1 = models.CharField()

class Model2(models.Model):
    a2 = models.CharField()
    model1 = ForeignKey(Model1)
```

I want to do something like this in

```
#views.py

def action(request):
    model1_instances = Model1.objects.all()
    render_to_respose('action.html', 'model1_instances': model1_instances, context_instance=RequestContext(request)
```

## What i want to do is ;

## For each 'model1_instances' object that gets passed to the action.html, i want its corresponding Model2 objects.

Tried using `model2_instance = model1_instances.model2_set.all()`, it was not giving the desired result and probably because model1_instances returns all the Model1 objects in the database.

## What i know

If i use something like;

```
model1_instance = Model1.objects.get(pk=1)
```

it is very easy to get the corresponding

```
model2_instance = model1_instance.model2_set.all().
```

I know this already and it is not what am looking for.

Need some clues guys.

## Solution

Thank you all for your contributions. I stumbled on this [API]: https://github.com/japsu/django-selectreverse and i decided to make use of it. Just like the saying goes "there is no need to re-invent the wheel". It worked and actually saved me a lot of headache and i can now focus my attention on something else.

Comment: Is a dictionary like this enough? `total_model2_instances = {model1_instance: model1_instance.model2_set.all() for model1_instance in model1_instances}`

Answer (score 1):

I think that the answer you are after has been answered over in another thread.

[Best practice to get related values in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1827240/best-practice-to-get-related-values-in-django-without-doesnotexist-error)

Off the top of my head though (untested), try something like this:

```
model2_instance = Model2.objects.filter(model1__pk=1)
```

Comment: That's not what am looking for, but thanks anyway. You have restricted the 'model2_instance' queryset to to model1 with pk = 1. I want something that will give the related Model2 objects for every 'model1_instances'.

Comment: Ah I got ya. Sorry. Will have a play and try get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

You would get the instance of Model1:

```
model1 = Model1.objects.get(pk=1)
```

Then to get the instance of Model2 that referenced it with its FK try this:

```
model2 = model1.Model2_set.all()
```

This will return the set of all Model2 instances that reference your instance of Model1.

I got the information for this from: [Backwards related objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#backwards-related-objects)

**EDIT:**
Get the related Model2 instances in the template rather than view:

```
{% for model1 in model1_instances %}
    {% for model2 in model1.Model2_set.all %}
    {{ model2 }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you once again. I have edit my OP for further clarification. You are not getting the gist. I what to use (in your case) model1 = Model1.objects.all() and then get the related Model2 instances.

Comment: Sorry again. If you find the answer please can you update this thread as I'm new to Django too :)

Comment: Maybe try getting the model2_set.all() in the template rather than the view? Not ideal but should get you what you want? Will update this answer. Hope I've understood you this time :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your contributions. I stumbled on this [API]: https://github.com/japsu/django-selectreverse and i decided to make use of it. Just like the saying goes "there is no need to re-invent the wheel". It worked and actually saved me a lot of headache and i can now focus my attention on something else.